# Checking if Username is taken

Tags: php, mysql

I've tried various things with my code to get it  test for an existing username but I cannot achieve it. It doesn't insert the database when the alphakey isn't correct. I've tried writing it but it won't seem work!

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    if (!empty($_POST['user']) && !empty($_POST['pass']) && !empty($_POST['alphakey'])) {
        //mysql_real_escape_string() escapes special characters in a string for use in an SQL statement
        $user     = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['user']);
        $pass     = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['pass']);
        $alphakey = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['alphakey']);

        $con = mysql_connect('localhost', '<UserName>', '<Password') or die(mysql_error());
        mysql_select_db('user') or die("cannot select DB");

        $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM login WHERE user='" . $user . "'");

        $numrows = mysql_num_rows($query);

        // if user doesn't exist...
        if ($numrows == 0) {
            $encrypt_password = md5($_POST["pass"]);
            $query_key = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM regkey WHERE alphakey='" . $_POST["alphakey"] . "'") or die(mysql_error());
            $check_key = mysql_num_rows($query_key);


            if ($check_key > 0) {
                $sql = mysql_query("INSERT INTO login (user,pass) 
                    VALUES ('" . $_POST["user"] . "','$encrypt_password')") or die(mysql_error());
            }
        } // brace for if($numrows==0)

        if ($sql) {
            echo "<center>Success, You're now registered</center><br/>";
        } else {
            echo "<center>Invalid Alpha Key, Please try again!</center><br/>";
        }
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: try this `$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM login WHERE user='$user'");`

Comment: better use prepared statements and [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php)

Comment: what is your **question**?? whats **error**??

Comment: Why not just use UNIQUE constraint on the `user` column?

Comment: My question is the title, I cannot seem to get my php code to check if the username exists and the error is that it doesn't check it at all.

Comment: Well first of all, you're giving not enough information. I'll ask some questions you need to answer. What is the error or what does it echo(if it even echoes something)? What is the result of: var_dump($numrows); right after you run that query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to check this,

```
$check_key = mysql_num_rows($query_key);


if($check_key < 1){

    $sql = mysql_query("INSERT INTO login (user,pass) 
                VALUES ('".$_POST["user"]."','$encrypt_password')") 

      or die(mysql_error());
    }
} // brace for if($numrows==0)
```

Comment: Will this answer my question?

Comment: I tried this and it doesn't do anything, all it does is just gives me the "Invalid Alpha Key" error.

Comment: mysql_num_rows returns int no need to use sizeof

Comment: Thanks for improving, I misjudged !